# implementing the MenuContainer

Tags: java, api, interface

I don't understand this question on my java study guide. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

What method/s must you write to implement the MenuContainer interface? (Do not include deprecated methods.)

http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/awt/class-use/MenuContainer.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand how to implement interfaces? If you do, please check the following link, which I think should answer your question:
http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/awt/MenuContainer.html